# Performance of std::map index operator vs insert method

Tags: c++, c++14, std, compiler-optimization

I recently saw a change in a pull request. I'm wondering whether that does any improvement.

Following is a simplified version.

```
...
std::map<int, std::string> myMap;
...  // map will get updated

void foo(int key, std::string value)
{    
    myMap[key] = value;  // <-- this line gets changed
}
```

The marked single line was changed as follows.

```
    auto entry = myMap.find(key);
    if (entry == myMap.end())
    {
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }
    else
    {
        entry->second = value;
    }
```

Maybe the intention was to avoid the creation of an object if `key` is not present (which seems a valid point). But doesn't a similar temporary object is created in `insert()` call? Or does some kind of optimization happen here?

In my opinion, both versions should have same performance. But there will be an improvement if `emplace()` is used instead of `insert()`.

Could someone clarify this if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: It is evident that the first version is more efficient.

Comment: maybe it's realted to this: http://www.forwardscattering.org/post/37.
An old issue anyway.

Comment: 1 million repetitions yielded 185ms, and post-change implementation yielded 198ms in my empirical test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless measured, saying anything about performance lose/gains is kinda pointless. Sure, first version is theoretically faster but only measurement can show how relevant theory is.

Saying that - in my opinion the point of the change is making the logic explicit - assign value or insert if value does not exists in map. The usage of `operator[]` with `std::map` is one of the more nasty quirks of the language. Since C++17 there is dedicated method for this - `insert_or_assign` which is as fast as `emplace` or `insert`.